# PersitenceContext injection in EJB module in Geronimo 3.0

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, openjpa, entitymanager, geronimo

I'm trying to inject a PersistenceContext using EJB3 annotations but geronimo doesn't inject dependency. It's an EAR project composed by an EJB and a WEB module.

EJB-module configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <ejb:openejb-jar
xmlns:app="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-2.0"
xmlns:bp="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:client="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-client-2.0"
xmlns:conn="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/connector-1.2"
xmlns:dep="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2" xmlns:ejb="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/openejb-jar-2.2"
xmlns:jaspi="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/geronimo-jaspi"
xmlns:log="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/loginconfig-2.0"
xmlns:name="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2" xmlns:pers="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:pkgen="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/pkgen-2.1" xmlns:sec="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-2.0"
xmlns:web="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1">
<dep:environment>
    <dep:moduleId>
        <dep:groupId>wedge</dep:groupId>
        <dep:artifactId>wedge-ejb</dep:artifactId>
        <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
        <dep:type>car</dep:type>
    </dep:moduleId>
    <dep:dependencies>
        <dep:dependency>
            <dep:groupId>console.dbpool</dep:groupId>
            <dep:artifactId>jdbc_wedgeDS</dep:artifactId>
            <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
            <dep:type>car</dep:type>
        </dep:dependency>
    </dep:dependencies>
</dep:environment>
```

I've configured persistence.xml as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="wedgePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/wedgeDS</jta-data-source>
            <class>wedge.entity.Aec</class>
            ...
            <class>wedge.entity.Tnr</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ManagedRuntime"
                value="jndi(TransactionManagerName=java:comp/TransactionManager)" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I've created datasource as Local TX Datasource, and is resolved ok.

I've defined an EJB as follows

```
    @Local(PruebaBL.class)
    @Stateless
    public class PruebaBLImpl {

        @PersistenceContext()
        private EntityManager em;

        @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
        public void metodoPrueba(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, NamingException {

            if (em == null) {
                response.getOutputStream().println("entity manager is null");
            }
```

I've verified that transaction begins/ends OK, but entityManager is not injected.

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Saul

Comment: I'm reading logs and debugging and I think the problem is how I'm trying to inject EJB into WebServlets. Do I need to specify the jndi global name in @EJB annotation? i.e. `@EJB (name=java:comp/env/global/wedge/wedge-ejb/PruebaBLImpl!wedge.ejb.PruebaBL)`. If this reference fails, Pojo will be created with 'new', and injection fails. It's correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the global jndi name. Inject it like this in your servlet:

```
@EJB
private PruebaBL pruebaBL;
```

Comment: I success deploying EJB in this way, even without @Local. The problem persists, and I'm not able to  use a persistenceContext injected in EJB and Servlet. I'll tray this weekend the same configuration with postgresql, deploying a different XA datasource. Thank you